# Unable to connect to server with Cordova-app on device

Tags: android, cordova, server

I have created an Android-app with Cordova and on an emulator it works like a charm. When I tried to run it on a device I didn't get past the login-screen because I got an error saying: "Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Is this a CSP issue within Cordova or is it something wrong with my server?
Some of Config.xml:

```
  <access origin="*" />
  <access origin="baseUrlToServer.com" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

And my CSP metatag in Index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *UrlToServer.com; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```

Have anyone stumbled across something similar and have an idea? Help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is server-side.

Your server has to respond with some `HTTP RESPONSE HEADERS` among which :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

### On apache2, for example

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That is covered trough CORS on the server.

Comment: Ok but there is something wrong with that if you get `Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

Comment: Ok, but on my server I have enabled `AllowAnyHeader();` `AllowAnyMethod()` `AllowAnyOrigin()` `AllowCredentials()` in ASP.NET 5. Are there any other things that comes to mind that I should maybe check out? Still having this issue ..

Comment: No it is these settings that matter. Maybe somewhere an other configuration topic overrides these ones. For example, have you a web server on front of your app like nginx or something like that? I think you should search in this direction.